# How to do the autocorrelation between the months of a timeseries dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, autocorrelation

I want to do the autocorrelation between the months of different years of a timeseries. The timeseries has just one column with the values corresponding to each date.

but my problem is that I get values greater than 1 as an answer, although they should be between -1 and +1. Is there any other way to do it? I've tried this approach:

```
    def data_autocorr(data, lag=12, axis=0):
        return data.apply(lambda col: col.autocorr(lag), axis=axis)
    d1 = DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 12))
    data_autocorr(d1)
```

Comment: Any specific reason you don't want to use `statsmodels` for computing `ACF`.?

Comment: BTW, you have only 12 datapoints, how can you do an ACF with 12 lags.?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. As @SreeramTP pointed out, your current example only returns `NaN`.